# See the whole HDRi image as cycles world

Tags: cycles-render-engine

When I open a hdri image for a world background , I get an extremely enlarged image on the screen  , showing only a very small part of the image . What can I do to fix that problem ?

Comment: The world is large. For example if you look out of the window of your house you only see a small part of it.